# Tensorflow Image Processing Function

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Guys I have made the tutorial of Basic Image Classification from Tensorflow.org. But I couldnt understand the codes of def image_process. Beceause there is no explanation in tutorial.

This is code:

```
def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
  true_label, img = true_label[i], img[i]
  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])

  plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)
  if predicted_label == true_label:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'red'

  plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                class_names[true_label]),
                                color=color)
```

**My Question:**

How the function determines predictions_array is predicted value and true label is the correct label. Shouldnt we say true_label = train_label[i] or predictions_array = prediction[i]

How does fuction determines objects while we are not set them in our function as I showed.

Comment: Can you show us how this method `plot_image` is called ?

Comment: I am very new to tensorflow the tutorail is from https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/keras/classification

Comment: I can share my colabs:https://colab.research.google.com/drive/13tAm-aVfoqzKGTH5ig9s9cHKKdILDzuH?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you please help me?

Comment: @mujjiga I am waiting your answer...

Comment: I can't access your notebook :(

Comment: Why that you cannot accsess so can you look at here : https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/docs/blob/master/site/en/tutorials/keras/classification.ipynb

Comment: @mujjiga can you please look at here?

Comment: @mujjiga I am waiting your answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets start with the train code (Documentation inline)

```
# TensorFlow and tf.keras
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras

# Helper libraries
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# load data
fashion_mnist = keras.datasets.fashion_mnist
(train_images, train_labels), (test_images, test_labels) = fashion_mnist.load_data()

# Text representation of labels
class_names = ['T-shirt/top', 'Trouser', 'Pullover', 'Dress', 'Coat',
               'Sandal', 'Shirt', 'Sneaker', 'Bag', 'Ankle boot']

# Normalize the train and test images
train_images = train_images / 255.0
test_images = test_images / 255.0

# Define the model
model = keras.Sequential([
    keras.layers.Flatten(input_shape=(28, 28)),
    keras.layers.Dense(128, activation='relu'),
    keras.layers.Dense(10)
])
model.compile(optimizer='adam',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

# train the model
model.fit(train_images, train_labels, epochs=10)
```

As you can see the last layer is a `Dense` layers of output size `10`. That is because we have 10 classes. To identify to which class it belongs to we can just take the max value out of those 10 and assign its class as its predictions. But if we can change these value to probabilities we can also tell how confident is the model in making this predictions. So lets attach softmax layers which normalized these 10 outputs to probabilities.

```
probability_model = tf.keras.Sequential([model, tf.keras.layers.Softmax()])
predictions = probability_model.predict(test_images)
print (f"Input: {test_images.shape}, Output: {predictions.shape}")
```

Output:

```
Input: (10000, 28, 28), Output: (10000, 10)
```

Lets print the predicted and the true label of ith test image

```
i = 0
print (f"Actual Label: {train_labels[i]}, Predicted Label: {np.argmax(predictions[i])}")
```

Output:

```
Actual Label: 9, Predicted Label: 9
```

Finally lets plot the ith image and label it with the predicted class and its probability. (Documentation inline)

```
def plot_image(i, predictions_array, true_label, img):
  """
  i: render ith image
  predictions_array: Probabilities of each class predicted by the model for the ith image
  true_label: All the the acutal label
  img: All the images
  """
  # Get the true label of ith image and the ithe image itself
  true_label, img = true_label[i], img[i]

  plt.grid(False)
  plt.xticks([])
  plt.yticks([])

  # Render the ith image
  plt.imshow(img, cmap=plt.cm.binary)

  # Get the class with the higest probability for the ith image
  predicted_label = np.argmax(predictions_array)

  if predicted_label == true_label:
    color = 'blue'
  else:
    color = 'red'

  plt.xlabel("{} {:2.0f}% ({})".format(class_names[predicted_label],
                                100*np.max(predictions_array),
                                class_names[true_label]),
                                color=color)
```

Finally lets call it

```
plot_image(i, predictions[i], test_labels, test_images)
```

[image]

You confusion is because of `predictions_array` parameters. Please note that it is the predictions made by the model for the ith test data. It has 10 values each of which represent the probability of it belonging to the corresponding class.

Comment: Thank you for your response but I still I couldnt understand how predictiction_array and true_label is defined as predictions[i] and train_image[i].

Comment: I will give a example to explain more. When we determine a variable in javascript dont we write the meaning of code directly. Just like this ------>>>> var true_label = train_images[i]. Maybe now I could explain myself more clearly.

Comment: And in our def image_process function we did not determine the variables just like I showed?

Comment: see this part `true_label, img = true_label[i], img[i]` the ith train_label is being assigned to itself. This is bad but thats what the code is.  Its like `a = a[i]` (in the scope of the function). Similary for `predictiction_array` we are passing `predictions[i]` so `predictiction_array` now contains predictions made for ith label Who ever wrote the function did a lousy joinb.

Comment: so automatically when we add a_label = a_label[i], it will be refer to train_label[i] right?

Comment: If `a_label` is a list of lables. When you do `a_label = a_label[i]` the variable  `a_label` which was initially a list of labels will be overwritten to the ithe value of the labels.

Comment: I mean = we do true_label = true_label[i] here. But ıf I change it as a_label = a_label[i] wouldnt it will be same?